# Download papers from IEEExplore with wget

Tags: ssh, download, wget, ieee

I am now out of institute, but need to download paper from IEEExplore.

I can ssh to the institute server. I think I should be able to access IEEExplore there, but I don't know how to download.

Suppose I am out of institute, and want to download this paper:

```
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=5738219&abstractAccess=no&userType=
```

I have tried:

```
wget http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?reload=true&arnumber=5738219&abstractAccess=no&userType=
-O mypaper.pdf
```

but mypaper.pdf turns out to be a broken pdf file.

Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: just to complete the solution. step1: ssh into the server, step2: use wget to download the paper, step3: use scp to copy the paper from the remote server to the local disk.

Answer (score 18):

I found http://techqe.blogspot.com/2009/09/quick-download-ieee-paper.html, which provides the following solution:

1. Identify the "arnumber" for the paper, in the hyperlink you found while browsing. In your example, it's 5738219
2. Enter the following command at your shell:

   ```
   wget "http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&isnumber=&arnumber=5738219" -O paper.pdf
   ```

Your paper will now be saved in "paper.pdf"

Comment: It seems not working any more, the command line returns an html page instead of a pdf.

Comment: tested - still works as of the date of this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your institute server as a socks proxy and download as usual using your favourite method.

`ssh -D <portNumber> username@serverip`

Now the socks proxy has been setup on `localhost:portNumber`. You can apply the proxy system wide based on your operating system and download as usual.